# Odd animation in UINavigationBar (UIBarButtonItem with custom view)

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, uibarbuttonitem

I'm trying to put a "pie-based countdown timer view" in a `UINavigationBar`.

The `UIView` subclass (cleverly called `ProgressView`) works fine when added to a standard `UIView`.

When I try to use it as a custom view for a `UIBarButtonItem` in a `UINavigationBar`/`UINavigationItem`, however, things get a bit wonky.

The reason is that, when the timer is finished counting down, the view turns into a green circle which shrinks down to a green dot to be less obtrusive.

I'm initializing the custom `UIBarButtonItem` like this:

```
self.progressView                      = [[ProgressView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 36, 36)];     
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:self.progressView];
```

Here's the code that runs at the end of the timer:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:1.0f
                      delay:1.0f
                    options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseInOut
                 animations:^{
                     self.transform = CGAffineTransformScale(self.transform, 0.25f, 0.25f);
                 }
                 completion:nil];
```

It doesn't seem to matter whether I use this:

```
self.transform = CGAffineTransformScale(self.transform, 0.25f, 0.25f);
```

or this:

```
self.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(0.25f, 0.25f);
```

When I monitor the `frame` property of the custom view by overriding the `-(void)setFrame:(CGRect)frame` accessor, I get the following output (testing on iPhone 6 Plus):

```
frame: {{0, 0}, {0, 0}}
frame: {{0, 0}, {36, 36}}
frame: {{358, 4}, {36, 36}} // <-- This displays 3 times for some reason
frame: {{385, 17}, {9, 9}}
```

Now, it's fairly apparent that the decrease (by 27 points) in the width of the frame is causing the `UINavigationBar`/`UINavigationItem` to shift the entire view to the right to maintain some buffer to the right edge of the screen. My calculations seem to indicate it's maintaining a 20 point buffer.

How can I animate the "shrinking" of my `UIView` without altering the frame? The drawing is so basic (it's just a green dot at this point), it can just "appear" to shrink, if there's some way to do that.

I'd be satisfied with some drawing trick that does it, but it seems that animating a transform is going to give the best appearance.

Answer (score 0):

With UIBezierPath / addArcWithCenter you can draw a circle.

You can simulate an animation as follows:
have a UIView class that receives the radius of your circle and draw your circle. (let's call her circle)

Has a method that starts the animation you want.
This method starts a timer that removes the subview circle (if it exists)
re-allocates the circle class, passing the new radius and adding it as a subview.

This is not exact your case, but I think will help.

In your button:

```
- (void)drawCircularProgressBarWithMinutesLeft:(NSInteger)minutes secondsLeft:(NSInteger)seconds
{
    // Removing unused view to prevent them from stacking up
    for (id subView in [self subviews]) {
        if ([subView isKindOfClass:[CircularProgressTimer class]]) {
            [subView removeFromSuperview];
        }
    }
   // Init our view and set current circular progress bar value
    CGRect progressBarFrame = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.bounds.size.width, self.bounds.size.height);
    self.progressTimerView = [[CircularProgressTimer alloc] initWithFrame:progressBarFrame ];
    [self.progressTimerView setCenter:CGPointMake(self.bounds.size.width/2, self.bounds.size.height/2)];
    [self.progressTimerView setPercent:seconds];

    // Here, setting the minutes left before adding it to the parent view
    [self.progressTimerView setMinutesLeft:minutes];
    [self.progressTimerView setSecondsLeft:seconds];
    [self addSubview:self.progressTimerView];
    self.progressTimerView = nil;
    [self setNeedsDisplay];
}
```

In a UIView (CircularProgressTimer)

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    // Create our arc, with the correct angles
    // The initialAngleFactor is the extra angular distance the stroke will cover from
    // angle zero to the desired initial angle. For example, if you want it to start from
    // angle zero, the factor will be zero. In this case, we'll start from 12 o'clock,
    // which is angle 3M_PI/2 or 1.5M_PI
    float initialAngleFactor = 1.5 * M_PI;
    UIBezierPath *bezierPath = [UIBezierPath bezierPath];
    [bezierPath addArcWithCenter:CGPointMake(rect.size.width / 2, rect.size.height / 2)
                          radius:rect.size.width / 2 - indiceGrossuraLinha
                      startAngle:0 + initialAngleFactor
                        endAngle:(_percent * M_PI) / 30.0 + initialAngleFactor
                       clockwise:YES];

    // Are you wondering where the previous formula comes from?
    // (_percent * M_PI) / 30.0 + initialAngleFactor
    // Well, M_PI covers just half of the circle, which can display as much as 30 seconds.
    // That's the number of pieces in which the half circle is divided: 30 on each piece.
    bezierPath.lineWidth = 5;
    [[UIColor colorWithRed:0.03f green:0.64f blue:0.90f alpha:1.00f] setStroke]; 
//    [[UIColor colorWithRed:0.64f green:0.81f blue:0.99f alpha:1.00f] setStroke];
    [bezierPath stroke];
}
```

A timer in my UIViewcontroller call drawCircularProgressBarWithMinutesLeft

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. Can you add some code that would explain your idea?